# Finding all neighbors for all polygons in Spatialite

Tags: spatialite

Excuse me if this is a basic question but I'm new to Spatialite...

I have a dataset with zip code polygons and I would like to create a list where for each zip code we have listed all the neighboring (i.e. adjacent) zip codes.

If I do the following it works but only for 1 zip code. What I would like to do is to repeat this automatically for all the zip codes in the data (since I have thousands of codes).

```
SELECT p1.ROWID, p1.ZCTA5CE10 FROM "US_zcta5_2010" p1, "US_zcta5_2010" p2
WHERE p2.ROWID=1 AND
Touches (p1.Geometry, p2.Geometry)=1;
```

I'm using the spatialite-gui on a Mac.

Answer (score 3):

Just take out the p2.ROWID=1, you'll end up with a full list.  You might want to throw in an ORDER BY to make a nicer list.

Edit:  Sorry, you'll need to adjust your output, to something like:

```
SELECT p1.ROWID, p1.ZCTA5CE10, p2.ZCTA5CE10 
FROM "US_zcta5_2010" p1, "US_zcta5_2010" p2 
WHERE Touches (p1.Geometry, p2.Geometry)=1;
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work but it takes a looong time to run (I'm not even sure it is still running). Since I have thousands of zip codes is there a more efficient way of doing this? Thanks again!!

Comment: I forgot that Spatialite doesn't use a spatial index by default, you'll have to manually join to the index table.  Here's a link from the Spatialite manual on how to use spatial indexes:  http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-3.0.0-BETA/spatialite-cookbook/html/rtree.html